# Arduino analogWrite() between two pins only working in one direction

Tags: arduino

I have a set of leds that are setup every other led reversed so when I apply power one way light 1,3,5... light. Change power and 2,4,6... I'm trying to set the brightness using PWM on the digital pins. Here's my code:

```
unsigned long flashCount = 0;
bool bSwitch = true;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if((flashCount + 1000) < millis())
  {
    if(bSwitch)
    {
      analogWrite(6, 0);
      analogWrite(7, 1);
      bSwitch = false;
    }
    else
    {
      analogWrite(7, 0);  
      analogWrite(6, 1);
      bSwitch = true;
    }
    flashCount = millis();
  }
}
```

If I change analogWrite to 255 instead of 1, it will switch both sets of leds. If I change analogWrite to 127 or less, only one set will light. If I switch the led wires to the pins, the problem switches to the other set of lights.

The leds are like so:

```
GPIO pin 6 --------.-LED+.---.-LED+.---.-LED+.---.-LED+.---|
GPIO pin 7 ---.+LED-.---.+LED-.---.+LED-.---.+LED-.--------|
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the LEDs are connected?

Comment: @bit - updated post

Comment: What do they connect to on the other side of the GPIO pin? Ground? Also not sure how 4 LEDs would reach the activation voltage to light them all up

Comment: @bit - Ok, let's make this simpler. When I analogWrite(6, 100) and analogWrite(7, 0) I get about 2vdc between 6 and 7. When I analogWrite(6,0) and analogWrite(7,100) I get 0vdc between 6 and 7. That is the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the connection of the LEDs to pins that both support PWM.

Not all pins support PWM. The [analogWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) documentation specifies which pins depending on which board:

> On most Arduino boards (those with the ATmega168 or ATmega328P), this function works on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11. On the Arduino Mega, it works on pins 2 - 13 and 44 - 46. Older Arduino boards with an ATmega8 only support analogWrite() on pins 9, 10, and 11.

The other factor is that `analogWrite(255)` and `analogWrite(0)` will revert to driving the output as a digital output. So writing 255 causes both pins to output (one as a digital output and the other in PWM mode). But writing 1 to 127 only causes the PWM capable pin to change.

Comment: This was my problem! I didn't know about the limitation. Thanks @blt

Answer (score 1):

From arduino's manpages:

Syntax
analogWrite(pin, value)

Parameters
pin: the pin to write to. Allowed data types: int.
value: the duty cycle: between 0 (always off) and 255 (always on). Allowed data types: int

Using an analogWrite with a value of 1 is essentially near-zero. 255 would be full voltage. You're attempting to use analogWrite() as if it was digitalWrite().

Consider using digital write instead in your code: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/

As for your LED's behavior, it seems like your circuit needs to be debugged as well: Your circuit will only allow current to flow when pin 7 is on. Diodes (Light Emitting Diodes) only allow current in one direction. If you're intending to have the LED's alternate, they should all be oriented with the positives pointing toward their GPIO pin and where they meet they should be grounded with a pull-down resistor.

Comment: updated post to show LED's no circuit. Just LED's and arduino. Can't use digitalWrite because I want PWM to dim the LED's.

Comment: Updated response with comment on circuit

Comment: digitalWrite() won't work. analogWrite() (pwm) is correct. There are many examples of this in the internet. Valid answer is above.